# Call a function via dict.get()

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to call a function with `dict.get()`.

```
def foo():
    print('foo')

def oof():
    print('oof')

a = {'f': foo,
     'o': oof}

a.get('f', 'None')
```

But it returns `object at 0x0...`, and if I call the function like `foo()` and `oof()`, it calls both and not only the requested function.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen with the `None` case? Nothing or throw an error?

Comment: @dawg is in case there is no key named 'f'

Comment: I understand that it is the default. My question is: What do you want to happen if there is no function named `f`? An error that stops the program or silently nothing?

Comment: Just nothing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your dictionary values are functions. However, you need to remember to actually call your function:

```
a.get('f', 'None')()
```

The result, as expected, is seeing "foo" printed:

```
foo
```

Notice the parentheses `()` to indicate we want to run the function. To discover what's happening you can also check the `type` of `a['f']`:

```
print(type(a['f']))

<class 'function'>
```

The method above, however, is inadvisable, because you can't call `None` if your key does not exist. In this case, you can catch `KeyError`:

```
def call_func(dispatcher, key):
    try:
        dispatcher[key]()
    except KeyError:
        return 'None'

call_func(a, 'f')
```

In practice, you will have functions with `return` statements, to avoid the inconsistency of having a function either print something (and return `None`) or return a string.

Comment: just careful about cases where `"None"` is returned

Comment: Or you could just do `a.get('f', lambda: 'None')()`. But I think the `KeyError` handling is more readable, even if a bit more verbose.